# Form values from my application is not getting saved in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Being a newbie to Node js and MongoDb, I created a simple form using HTML to get feedbacks. So when I submit my form, I am getting an output that my data is saved, but essential I am not able to see any data in the database. Below is the full code.

HTML:

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post">
    Name <input type = "Name" name=value=""> <br><br>
    Roll No <input type = "text" value=""> <br><br>
    Meal <input type = "text" value=""> <br><br>
    Quality <input type = "text" value=""> <br><br>
    Comments <input type = "text" value=""> <br> <br>

    <input type = "submit" value ="submit">
</form>
```

app.js:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.Promise=global.Promise;
 var app=express();
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/feedback');

 var feebackschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: String,
    Rollno: String,
    Meal: String,
    Quality: String,
    Comments: String
 });

 var feed = mongoose.model('feed',feebackschema);
 module.exports=feed
 app.get("/", function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html"); 
 })
 app.post("/feedback", function(req,res){
     var mydata=new feed(req.body);

     mydata.save()
     .then(item =>{
        res.send("Data saved");
     })
     .catch(err=>{
        res.send("Data not saved");
     })
 })

 app.listen(4000, function(){
     console.log("Server listening on 4000");
 })
```

EDIT:
HTML

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post">
    Name <input type = "Name" name= "name" value=""> <br><br>
    Roll No <input type = "text" name="rollno" value=""> <br><br>
    Meal <input type = "text" name="Meal" value=""> <br><br>
    Quality <input type = "text" name="quality" value=""> <br><br>
    Comments <input type = "text" name="comments" value=""> <br> <br>

    <input type = "submit" value ="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the value of `req.body` inside the route handler?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. the req.body is empty. So I went back to check my HTML, and found that the "name" attribute of the "input" tag was missing. After adding that, the values are getting populated in the database.